# Determine the value of combined functions with square roots

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, graphing-functions

The question I have is to determine the value of $f(g(x))$ given $f(x)=\sqrt{16-x^2}$ and $g(x)=x^2$

I know generally how to tackle these kinds of questions, but I am not sure what to do when there is a square root in the question.

If someone could help me with one of these questions, I'd really appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

$f(g(x)) = f(x^2) = \sqrt{16-(x^2)^2} = ....$Can you continue?